# Power Query: Need to get total records returned by API in a variable

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am making API call in Power BI:

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents( APIURL & "/commonapi/search?name=myName&eCode=FCD&recordStart=1&recordLimit=1")),
    Total = Source[results-total]
```

The response JSON is:

[image]

I want to get the results-total which is 152 in variable "Total". But I am getting error in line

```
 Total = Source[results-total]
```

as "results-total" is inside the "responseHeader" in JSON.
What can be the correct code line for Total = Source[results-total]?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Can you please provide the sample `JSON` that `Source` returns

Answer (score 0):

Got resolution.

```
Total = Source[resposeHeader][results-total]
```